# SonataAdmin how to set default value for ModelAutocompleteType

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin

for example: I have an article belongs to category,

```
class ArticleAdmin extends AbstractAdmin{
protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
    {
        $formMapper
            ->add('category', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [
                'property' => 'title'
            ])
        ;
    }
}
```

It is using `ModelAutocompleteType` form type, But it is unable to set default value by `data` option.

Answer (score 0):

The default-value in a symfony form is provided by the `empty_data` option.

More information about the option can be found in the documentation chapter:

- [How to Configure empty Data for a Form Class](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/use_empty_data.html)

```
$formMapper
    ->add('category', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [
        'property' =>  'title',
        'class' => Category::class
        'empty_data' => function() {
             $category = new Category();
             $category->setTitle('This is a title');

             return $blogPost;
        }),
    ])
```

... or with a repository ...

```php
/** @var CategoryRepository */
protected $repository;

public function __construct(CategoryRepository $repository)
{
    $this->repository = $repository;
}

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $repository = $this->repository;
    $formMapper
        ->add('category', ModelAutocompleteType::class, [
            'property' =>  'title',
            'class' => Category::class
            'empty_data' => function() use ($repository) {
                 return $repository->findOneById(1);
            }),
        ])
    ;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, if your answer is right, the default value should be selected in the form field, but it is still show empty and no default value is selected